# Getting gulp to work with livereload

Tags: sass, livereload, gulp

I have got my `Gulpfile` to compile my `sass` and am only a "`live-reload` away from dumping `codekit`". I am struggling getting this style injection to work though. I am trying to set this up: https://github.com/vohof/gulp-livereload

And when i run gulp in the terminal it seems that it compiles the sass, but it doesnt inject the styles. What am i doing wrong? I installed the livereload extention in chrome + the following node modules:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "~3.5.0",
    "gulp-sass": "~0.6.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "gulp-livereload": "~0.2.0",
    "tiny-lr": "0.0.5"
  }
```

And my gulpfile looks like this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

//plugins
var sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    lr = require('tiny-lr'),
    livereload = require('gulp-livereload'),
    server = lr();

gulp.task('sass', function () {
    gulp.src('./scss/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./'))
        .pipe(livereload(server));
});


// Rerun tasks when a file changes
gulp.task('watch', function () {
    server.listen(35729, function (err) {

        if (err) return console.log(err);

        gulp.watch('scss/**/*.scss', ['sass']);

    });
});





// The default task (called when you run 'gulp' from cli)
// "sass" compiles the sass to css
// "watch" looks for filechanges, and runs tasks accordingly
gulp.task('default', ['sass', 'watch']);
```

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by 'it doesn't inject the styles' ? Is it compiling your sass to the correct directory?

Comment: Yes. my index.html is linking to this: <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

Comment: And when i reload the browser the styles take effect. But i have to do it manually

Comment: are you running off localhost? Go into the settings from the plugin in Chrome and check the option for file urls

Comment: Do you have the livereload plugin installed *and* enabled in your browser?  (Alternatively, you can use [gulp-embedlr](https://npmjs.org/package/gulp-embedlr) to inject the LR javascript into your webpage with no browser plugin.)

Comment: @BrianGlaz That was exactly my problem. Thank you so much! If you leave that as an answer - ill accept that. Thank you. Silly mee.

Comment: I just posted a working sample of a an express static server, gulp and livereload.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

are you running off localhost? Go into the settings from the plugin in Chrome and check the option for file urls: chrome://extensions/

Answer (score 4):

If you're using `gulp-livereload`, I think there is no point in using `tiny-lr` as well.

You can find a working example of LiveReload integration here:

https://github.com/kriasoft/spa-seed.front-end - SPA Front-end Starter Kit

Comment: I had problems before using only gulp-livereload if you want to use a port different of the default one. Using tiny-lr solved this problem

Comment: gulp-livereload works fine without tiny-lr:
livereload = require('gulp-livereload');
var lr = livereload.listen( { port: 12345, auto: false } );
..and later...
.pipe( livereload( { port: 12345 } ) )

Answer (score 4):

Just came across this fantastic tutorial explaining all the points to get Livereload up and running with Gulp:

http://rhumaric.com/2014/01/livereload-magic-gulp-style/

Answer (score 2):

## This is my solution

- In need only this npm modules
  `npm install gulp gulp-sass gulp-livereload express --save-dev`
- Put the Scss-Files in `/app/styles` and Html-Files in `/app/`
- Install the [live-reload-plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/livereload/jnihajbhpnppcggbcgedagnkighmdlei) for Chrome.
- Go to http://localhost:4000 and activate the pluin for the current tab

Done :-)

(Don't forget to change the sass-settings for your Project. Set `indentedSyntax` to `false` if you are using scss instead of sass)

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
  sass = require('gulp-sass'),
  livereload = require('gulp-livereload');

gulp.task('sass', function() {
  gulp.src('app/styles/*.sass')
    .pipe(sass({
      includePaths: ['app/styles'],
      indentedSyntax : true,
      errLogToConsole: true
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'))
    .pipe(livereload());
});

gulp.task('serve', function(done) {
  var express = require('express');
  var app = express();
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/app'));
  app.listen(4000, function () {
     done();
  });
});

gulp.task('html', function() {
  gulp.src('app/**/*.html')
    .pipe(livereload());
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch('app/styles/*.sass', ['sass']);
  gulp.watch('app/**/*.html', ['html']);

  livereload.listen();
});

gulp.task('default', ['watch', 'serve']);
```

Answer (score 2):

I had enabled livereload via browser extensions, but the last thing I needed to do was to click this button to "activate" it on the individual tab.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I got gulp and livereload running without the need of browser plugins.

```
var http = require('http')
, path = require('path')
, Promise = Promise || require('es6-promise').Promise
, express = require('express')
, gulp = require('gulp')
, log = require('gulp-util').log
, tinylr = require('tiny-lr')
, livereload = require('gulp-livereload')

, ROOT = 'dist'
, GLOBS = [path.join(ROOT, "/**/*")]
, PORT = 8000
, PORT_LR = PORT + 1

, app = express()
;

app.use(require('connect-livereload')({port: PORT_LR}))
app.use('/', express.static("./dist"))

http.createServer(app).listen(PORT, function() {
  log("Started express server on http://localhost:" + PORT);
});

lrUp = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  lrServer = tinylr()
  lrServer.listen(PORT_LR, function(err) {
    if (err) return reject(err)
    resolve(lrServer)
  })
})

gulp.watch(GLOBS, function(evt) {
  if (evt.type === 'deleted') return

  lrUp.then(function(lrServer) {
    log("LR: reloading", path.relative(ROOT, evt.path));
    gulp.src(evt.path).pipe(livereload(lrServer))
  })
  .catch(console.log)
});
```

enjoy :)